# What is the genetic explanation for gall forming in erythrina by gall wasp?

Tags: genetics, entomology

[image]

http://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/46220

Gall wasp  layed egg in the stem of the erythrina variegata,  the larva make gall, I like to know how the gall formation occurs in erythrina variegata